# Broadcast through numpy array with list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an adjacency list:

```
adj_list = [array([0,1]),array([0,1,2]),array([0,2])]
```

And an array of indices,

```
ind_arr = array([0,1,2])
```

Goal:

```
A = np.zeros((3,3))
for i in ind_arr:
    A[i,list(adj_list[x])] = 1.0/float(adj_list[x].shape[0])
```

---

---

Currently, I have written:

```
A[ind_list[:],adj_list[:]] = 1. / len(adj_list[:])
```

And tried various configurations of indexing within this scaffold.

Comment: Would the array elements of `adj_list` always be in that sequence format - `[0,1,2...]`?

Comment: @Divakar they are in ascending order.  But, they are sparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
lens = np.array([len(i) for i in adj_list])
col_idx = np.concatenate(adj_list)
out = np.zeros((len(lens), col_idx.max()+1)) 
row_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(len(lens)), lens)
vals = np.repeat(1.0/lens, lens)
out[row_idx, col_idx] = vals
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [494]: adj_list = [np.array([0,2]),np.array([0,1,4])]

In [496]: out
Out[496]: 
array([[ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.33333333]])
```

**Sparse matrix as output**

Additionally, if you want to save memory and create a sparse matrix instead, that's an easy extension -

```
In [506]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

In [507]: csr_matrix((vals, (row_idx, col_idx)), shape=(len(lens), col_idx.max()+1))
Out[507]: 
<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [508]: _.toarray()
Out[508]: 
array([[ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.33333333]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can completely eliminate loops due to the mixed data types, but you can reduce the nested double for loops to a single one:

```
A = np.zeros((2, 3))
for i, arr in enumerate(adj_list):
    arr_size = len(arr)
    A[i, :arr_size] = 1./arr_size

A
# array([[ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.33333333]])
```

Or if the numbers in the arrays are actually columns positions:

```
A = np.zeros((2, 3))
for i, arr in enumerate(adj_list):
    A[i, arr] = 1./len(arr)

A
# array([[ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.33333333]])
```

---

Another option using `MultiLabelBinarizer` from `sklearn`(but may not be as efficient):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
​
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

adj_list = [np.array([0,1]),np.array([0,1,2])]
​
sizes = np.fromiter(map(len, adj_list), dtype=int)
mlb.fit_transform(adj_list)/sizes[:,None]

# array([[ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.33333333]])
```